# No info in FB feed dialog when picture is missing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

I'm trying to post to Facebook using the **FBConnect** sdk.
When I supply the link for the picture, everything works fine.
[image]

But when the picture is missing, none of the other info's are shown.
[image]

Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug in FBConnect.
The code is:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [params setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
        [params setValue:address forKey:@"caption"];
        [params setValue:descrption forKey:@"description"];
        [params setValue:website forKey:@"link"];
        if(thumbnail.serverPath)
            [params setValue:thumbnail.serverPath forKey:@"picture"];

        [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured the problem with the missing information in the **feed dialog**.
Turned out that, to display the info properly, either **link** or **picture** must be set in the  *params* dictionary.
Not sure, why it is so. But anyway, the new code which solved the problem is:

```
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [params setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
        [params setValue:address forKey:@"caption"];
        [params setValue:descrption forKey:@"description"];
        [params setValue:website forKey:@"link"];
        if(thumbnail.serverPath)
            [params setValue:thumbnail.serverPath forKey:@"picture"];

        //IMPORTANT
        //Before posting check that there is a valid link for the picture. 
        //If not, then add  
        //to ensure that rest of the info is displayed correctly in the feed.
        if(![params valueForKey:@"picture"]) {
            [params setValue:@"http://www.abc.com/images/xyz.png" forKey:@"picture"];
        }

        [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```